# In awesome window manager, how can I make key bindings send keyboard events?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, awesome

I don't think that title probably helps very much, but here's my issue:

I'm using the awesome window manager and am trying to make my key bindings to be similar in flavor to OSX for special keys.  I'm learning German, so I somewhat regularly need to type vowels with umlauts (double dots) above them.  In OSX, to do this, you type Alt+U, then the vowel you want.

Obviously, that won't be feasible in awesome, but what I do want is modkey+ to send a keyboard event that gives it the impression I had hit an umlaut-ed  key.

Would I have to change the keyboard layout first?  Such that the code changes the layout, sends the corresponding event, then changes it back?  Or can I send the event without changing the layout?

And how do I send the event in the first place, if that's possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do this via [Xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) and not via your window manager. This is directly related to your keyboard layout/keymap and not your window manager.

To change your xmodmap create a file named `~/.Xmodmap` and add the following content. This should allow you to to type üäöß directly with altgr+u

```
keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S ssharp section
```

Afterwards you have to apply the content from this file with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`

Another way to input umlauts is to use the us international layout. This allows you to enter umlauts with " + char. To enter ä you would need to enter `"a`. The international layout is also available in Windows and as far as i know in OSX.

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

Comment: However the window manager *(specifically the Awesome WM)* have a feature that it doesn't allow its keybindings to be intercepted by VirtualBox. I don't think that setxkbmap can help here.

Answer (score 11):

You can set up a compose key for all sorts of [different key sequences](http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html).

There are specific instructions [for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey), but they assume that you are running a Desktop Environment like Gnome or Xfce.

If you are using awesome as a standalone window manager, you can set a compose key in your `.xinitrc` file like so (this example uses the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key):

```
setxkbmap -option compose:ralt
```

Then, to compose an ä, for example, you would hit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RAlt</kbd>,<kbd>"</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>

You can read more about the Compose key on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the Compose key, you can also set up a key to select the so-called ‘third level’ by selecting one of the ‘international’ keyboard layouts. On Debian, I use ‘English (international AltGr dead keys)’. On PC keyboards, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is actually *meant* for this purpose, and X likes to assign it to the third level shift by default. You can also do this explicitly.

All you need to make this work is hold down <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and press a key on the keyboard (it's basically another shift key). This is exactly the way this works on the Mac too.

Accents are more intuitively accessible than umlauts. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> issues **á**. The umlaut version uses a key near the vowel key on the keyboard:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> → **ä**

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → **ë** (ok, not an *umlaut*; only listing it for completeness)

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> → **ï** (ditto)

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> → **ö**

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> → **ü**

Press these with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down to get the upper case versions, e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> → **Ä**.