# Control-q-? key binding in Awesome WM

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, awesome, lua

I wish to configure my Awesome Window Manager so that the keyboard shortcuts begin with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, and so on...

I've attempted to modify the `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua` config file, I've looked for answers, and I've reviewed the relevant man pages. I've even attempted to use `xmodmap` to accomplish this.

I've managed to change the Mod key to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, but I can't get the `awful.key` object to accept an additional modifier key.

Comment: I eventually gave up on AwesomeWM.

RatPoison accomplishes this very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome is pretty awesome, so is wmfs2/ratpoison. However you should be able to,

```
modkey = "Control" -- Under the require keys
```

modkey is used in the default configurations so if you didn't stray too far from the defaults this should work like a charm.

For three Key Mapping you could also have the following,

```
awful.key({ modkey, "q"   }, "j", function () awful.client.swap.byidx(  1)    end),
```

So inside the {} are the keys your would hold together, and the "j" is the key used to trigger the action respectively.

In your case i would have set modkey1 = "q" then replaced the above example with { modkey, modkey1 }

Good luck with RatPoison :)

Kyle

Comment: I was able to have the modkey be Control. I got that far.

Thank you, but your response does not explain how to have a three-key keyboard mapping.

Comment: Sorry i missed your main point... -_- hopefully the edit helps to solve this if you choose to use Awesome again, also i understand that you cant have one var (modkey) with two keys inside it. xmod does look like a better place to do it

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39078/in-awesome-window-manager-how-can-i-make-key-bindings-send-keyboard-events?rq=1